# SQL Syntax for is null or true or both

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I would like to do create a query that shows if one condition is null or the second condition is true but I don't want them to show if they are both true.
IE
If condition one is null or condition 2 is true but don't show if Condition 1 is not null and condition 2 is true.
EG
If Closed is null or NFA is true return the row else if closed is not null and nfa is true don't return the row.
I'm having trouble with the 'else'

```
WHERE (((Closed) Is Null)) OR (((tblDataDetail.ddt_nfa)=True)) else (???
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS Access? (Remove the unrelated tag.)

Comment: `where (A and NOT B) or (NOT A and B)`

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I cannot make out whether you are trying to describe `XOR`, `AND` or something else. Both [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_xor) and [MS Access](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/table-of-operators-e1bc04d5-8b76-429f-a252-e9223117d6bd#__toc272228350) support the exclusive or operator so just `A XOR B`.

Here is a logic table based on your description and possible outcomes:

| **Closed** | **ddt_nfa** | **Closed IS NULL (A)** | **ddt_nfa = TRUE (B)** | **A XOR B** | **A AND B** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | FALSE | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| NULL | TRUE | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | FALSE | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | TRUE | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |